# Best way to do this?

Tags: magento2, sorting, array

I've been racking my brains for a long time trying to think of the best most efficient way to solve the following problem.

Basically I have a set of questions which I'm looping through in the following way

```
// create array called $questionSets;

//loop through each question
  // get each answer from collection where the questionId matches the current question id

  // loop through each answer in the collection
    // add a new array to $questionSets array, which contains the current question title, as well as answer etc.


what I'm looking for, is to have something the following as a final array

Answer Sets Array [
  'set1' = [
    'this is the 1st question', 'this is the 1st answer given',
    'this is the 2nd question', 'this is the 2nd answer given'
  ],
  'set2' = [
    'this is the first question', 'this is the 1st answer given',
    'this is the first question', 'this is the 2nd answer given'
  ]
];

etc etc...

I'm just not sure of the best to approach to this one. I know it's probably a lot more simple than I'm thinking it will be, but I have spent a ton of time on this already and can't see the woods for the trees any more, lol :D 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys!
```

Comment: are questions and answers in the same collection or different?

Comment: the questions are being pulled in from a separate collection to the answers being given